# TThread checksynchronize issue with dll

Tags: multithreading, delphi

i have this TThread that i use inside my dll to update some visual control its working fine but i face issue when i try to close my dll and reopen it again its raised this exception

> checksynchronize called from thread which is not the main thread

what iam doing wrong ? i need to call `checksynchronize` within timer because i will update some vcl with Threading while app running .

Here is my Thread unit

```
unit Thread;

interface

uses Messages, Windows, SysUtils, dialogs, Classes, Menus, forms, ComOBJ,
  ShlObj;

{ Thread client }

type
  TThreadCallbackProc = procedure(Sender: TObject; Updatestring : string) of object;

  TAPPTHREAD = class(TThread)
  private
     Fstatus : String;
    FOnCallbackProc: TThreadCallbackProc;
    procedure dosomework;
    procedure DoCallbackProc;
    //
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;

  Public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; aThreadCallbackProc: TThreadCallbackProc);
    destructor Destroy; override;

  end;

  var
  APPTHREAD : TAPPTHREAD;




implementation


constructor TAPPTHREAD.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean;
  aThreadCallbackProc: TThreadCallbackProc);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FOnCallbackProc := aThreadCallbackProc;
end;

destructor TAPPTHREAD.Destroy;
begin
//
end;

procedure TAPPTHREAD.DoCallbackProc;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnCallbackProc) then
    FOnCallbackProc(self, Fstatus);
end;

procedure TAPPTHREAD.Execute;
begin

  while not Terminated do
  begin
    Fstatus := 'Synched';
    if Fstatus <> '' then
      dosomework;
  end;
end;



procedure TAPPTHREAD.dosomework;
begin

if Assigned(FOnCallbackProc) then
begin
Synchronize(DoCallbackProc);
end;

end;

end.
```

Main Form

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Timer2: TTimer;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure callbackproc(Sender: TObject; Updatestring : String);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
uses Thread;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.callbackproc(Sender: TObject; Updatestring: String);
begin
label1.Caption := updatestring;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
Action := Cafree;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin

try
if Assigned(APPTHREAD) then
AppThread.Terminate;
except end;

try 
Timer2.Enabled := False;
except end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
Timer1.Enabled := False;
APPTHREAD := TAPPTHREAD.Create(false, CallbackProc);
Timer2.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
Checksynchronize;
end;

end.
```

DFM

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 242
  ClientWidth = 472
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnClose = FormClose
  OnDestroy = FormDestroy
  OnShow = FormShow
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 472
    Height = 13
    Align = alTop
    Caption = 'Label1'
    ExplicitLeft = 232
    ExplicitTop = 136
    ExplicitWidth = 31
  end
  object Timer1: TTimer
    Enabled = False
    OnTimer = Timer1Timer
    Left = 232
    Top = 128
  end
  object Timer2: TTimer
    Enabled = False
    Interval = 1
    OnTimer = Timer2Timer
    Left = 320
    Top = 168
  end
end
```

dll code

```
library dllapp;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Themes,
  Windows,
  Forms,
  dialogs,
  Graphics,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Unit1},
  DThreadsend in 'Thread.pas';




var
  mHandle: THandle;
  DLLHandle: Longint = 0;

function createApp(Width: Integer; Height: Integer; hw: HWnd;
  app: TApplication): boolean; stdcall;
begin

  mHandle := CreateMutex(nil, True, 'APPNAMETLOAD');
  if GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS then
  begin
    Halt;
  end;

  try
    form1 := Tform1.CreateParented(hw); // **
    form1.Width := Width;
    form1.Height := Height;
    Result := True
  except
    on e: exception do
    begin
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure closeApp; stdcall;
begin
  ApplicationClosed := True;
  try
    if mHandle <> 0 then
      CloseHandle(mHandle);
  except
  end;
  if Assigned(form1) then
    try
      FreeAndNil(form1);
    except
    end;
  try
    OptimizeRamUsage;
  except
  end;
end;



procedure showapp; stdcall;
begin

  try
    form1.Visible := True;
  except
  end;
  form1.Show;
end;



procedure DLLEntryProc(EntryCode: Integer);
begin
  case EntryCode of
    DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
      begin
        StyleServices.Free;
      end;
    DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      begin

      end;
    DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
      begin

      end;
    DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
      begin

      end;
  end;
end;

exports
  closeApp,
  createApp,
  showapp;

begin

  DllProc := @DLLEntryProc;


end.
```

---

Host Application and how i create Dll

loadapp Unit

```
unit loadapp;

interface
uses windows, forms, System.SysUtils , dialogs;

procedure loadmainapp;

type
  TcreaFunc = function (Width: Integer; Height: Integer; hw:HWnd; app: TApplication): boolean; stdcall;
  TshowFunc = procedure stdcall;
  TCloseAppFunc = procedure stdcall;


  var
  dllHandle : THandle = 0;
  creaFunc : TcreaFunc;
  showFunc : TshowFunc;
  CloseAppFunc: TCloseAppFunc;

implementation
 uses  Mainapp;

procedure loadmainapp;
var
  S: widestring;
  PW: PWideChar;
begin
S := 'dllapp.dll';

  pw:=pwidechar(widestring(s));
  dllHandle := LoadLibrary(pw);
  if dllHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    @creaFunc := GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 'createApp');
    @showFunc := GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 'showapp');
    if Assigned (creaFunc) then
    begin
      creaFunc(mainfrm.panel1.Width, mainfrm.panel1.Height, mainfrm.panel1.Handle, Application);
      DisFunc;
    end
    else
      ShowMessage('ERROR');

  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('ERROR');
  end;
end;

end.
```

Active Form

```
unit activeform;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  ActiveX, AxCtrls, Frmldr_TLB, StdVcl, Vcl.ExtCtrls, ShlObj, Vcl.StdCtrls, SHDocVw, MSHTML;

type
  TActiveFrmldr = class(TActiveForm, IActiveFrmldr)
    mpanl: TPanel;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }

  protected
    { Protected declarations }

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;







implementation

uses ComObj, ComServ, Mainapp, libacload;

{$R *.DFM}

{ TActiveFrmldr }


procedure TActiveFrmldr.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
if dllHandle <> 0 then
begin
@CloseAppFunc := GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 'closeApp');
CloseAppFunc;
FreeLibrary(dllHandle);  //release dll
end;


if Assigned(mainfrm) then
try
FreeAndNil(mainfrm);
except
end;

end;

procedure TActiveFrmldr.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
Timer1.Enabled := False;
mainfrm.Parent := mpanl;
mainfrm.Left := 0;
mainfrm.Top  := 0;
mainfrm.Width := self.Width;
mainfrm.Height := self.Height;
mainfrm.Align := alClient;
mainfrm.Show;
end;


procedure TActiveFrmldr.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Application.CreateForm(Tmainfrm, mainfrm);
Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

initialization
  TActiveFormFactory.Create(
    ComServer,
    TActiveFormControl,
    TActiveFrmldr,
    Class_ActiveFrmldr,
    0,
    '',
    OLEMISC_SIMPLEFRAME or OLEMISC_ACTSLIKELABEL,
    tmApartment);

finalization

end.
```

Main app Form that call load library function

```
unit Mainapp;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, System.SysUtils, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, System.Classes, libacload,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  Tmainfrm = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Timer2: TTimer;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }

  end;


var
  mainfrm: Tmainfrm;

implementation
Uses loadapp;

{$R *.dfm}



procedure Tmainfrm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure Tmainfrm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin

Timer1.Enabled := False;

loadmainapp;

end;

procedure Tmainfrm.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin 
checksynchronize; // i do this to check some thread in activex it self 
end;

end.
```

Comment: You showed your thread code and your GUI code, but where is your DLL code? Who is (re)loading the DLL and when? When and where does the DLL create its GUI?

Comment: @RemyLebeau dll code added i use that dll as load library inside activex when ie reloaded that synchronize error starts i will look into your answer

Comment: You are creating your GUI in an exported function named `createApp()`.  What thread context does the calling process call `createApp()` in?  Sounds like it is not the same thread context that is loading the DLL.  Also, why are you freeing the `StyleServices` object manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error means that `CheckSynchronize()` is being called in a thread whose ThreadID does not match the RTL's global `System.MainThreadID` variable.

A DLL does not have a main thread of its own.  `MainThreadID` gets initialized to whatever thread is initializing the DLL.  So, if your DLL is creating its GUI in a different thread than the one that is initializing your DLL, `CheckSynchronize()` (and `TThread.Synchronize()`, and `TThread.Queue()`) will not work unless you manually update the `MainThreadID` variable to the ThreadID that is running your GUI.  Do that before creating your worker thread, eg:

```
if IsLibrary then
  MainThreadID := GetCurrentThreadID;
Form1 := TForm1.Create(nil);
```

Or:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IsLibrary then
    MainThreadID := GetCurrentThreadID;
end;
```

Or:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  if IsLibrary then
    MainThreadID := GetCurrentThreadID;
  APPTHREAD := TAPPTHREAD.Create(false, CallbackProc);
  Timer2.Enabled := True;
end;
```

Comment: after deep looking  the check synchronize error shows on activex form each time i refresh the ie check synchronize error raised i added the activeform and all code needed in the question